# jQuery .html() is not working

Tags: jquery, html

My objective seems simple enough. When the mouse enters an image, I'd like the image to expand in size and change to a slightly different version of the image. When the mouse leaves the image, I'd like it to shrink again and change back. My code isn't accomplishing this, and I'm not sure why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#home").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#home").animate({
      width: "10%",
      left: "4%",
      top: "0%"
    });
    $("#home").html("<a href='home.php'><img src='image/home.png'></a>");

    /*It works fine up 'til here, but after this point I get no response
    even clicking the link doesn't work. If I comment out the previous line of
    code, everything works as expected (excepting of course that the HTML
    doesn't change). It is quite confounding - the next bit of code is almost 
    a duplicate, and it gives me no trouble at all!*/

  });
  $("#home").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("#home").animate({
      width: "8%",
      left: "5%",
      top: "2%"
    });
    $("#home").html("<a href='home.php'><img src='image/d.png'></a>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="home">
  <a href='home.php'>
    <img src="image/d.png">
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you replacing the contents of the `li` when you could just change the `src` on the `img`?

Comment: If you want to change the image source, just change the image source. I think the problem is that you are replacing the entire DOM subtree of the element with id "home" with entirely new DOM elements. (and that probably interferes with the animate when the DOM tree is replaced out from under it)

Comment: @PaulAbbott No particular reason except habit. I'm not eager to make that change unless I have to. I already have other code doing other things to the list item that would need to be changes, and I'd have to go back and recalculate to resize an image instead of its container. I'll do those things if that's the best way of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the following line

```
$("#home").html("<a href='home.php'><img src='image/home.png'></a>");
```

with

```
//on mouseenter
$("#home img").attr('src','image/home.png');

//and same for mouseleave
$("#home img").attr('src','image/d.png');
```

Comment: This solution works, but I still don't understand exactly why my former code didn't. Any hints for the sake of my education?

Comment: you were removing img tag and overwriting another, thats why mousemove and moseleave events also removed

Comment: changing the image source may cause a lag in the transition unless you preload the second image before.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, what you are trying to do needs a different approach.
Load the two images at the beginning and when hover hide the first image.

Also scaling the image will be easier and cleaner using CSS.

Take a look: [**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/315/Image-toggle-with-hover-effects)

HTML:

```
<div id='toggleImage'>
  <img class='onMouseIn' src='dummy/250x250' />
  <img class='onMouseOut' src='dummy/250x250/png/d6e8ff' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#toggleImage {
  margin:0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  transition-duration:300ms;
  transition-property:transform;
  transition-timing-function:ease;
}
#toggleImage img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

JS(jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggleImage').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).children('.onMouseOut').fadeOut(300);
            $(this).css({'transform':'scale(1.2)'});
        },
        function(){
            $(this).children('.onMouseOut').fadeIn(300);
            $(this).css({'transform':'scale(1)'});
        }
    );
});
```